# Cap deploy doesn't work all the sudden; something to do with FactoryGirl and assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline, factory-bot

I've been `cap deploy`ing my app all throughout it development, and this last time I tried to deploy it, it didn't work. Here's what happened:

```
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /var/www/oneteam/releases/20121006153136 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["electricsasquatch.com"]
    [electricsasquatch.com] executing command
 ** [out :: electricsasquatch.com] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: electricsasquatch.com] uninitialized constant OneTeam::Application::FactoryGirl
 ** [out :: electricsasquatch.com] 
 ** [out :: electricsasquatch.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It looks like it failed on the `deploy:assets:precompile` command. I don't get why that command would have tried to do anything with FactoryGirl, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not that something is wrong with `deploy:assets:precompile` task, but something is wrong with rake task that is using FactoryGirl. Even if you place a syntax error let us say in `lib/tasks/first.rake` and you execute task from `lib/tasks/second.rake` for instance `rake second` the rake will scream with `rake aborted!`. Even `rake -T` will not work. So there is rake task that is trying to use FactoryGirl but FactoryGirl is not included.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Any suggestions on how to try to pinpoint that rake task?

Comment: `uninitialized constant OneTeam::Application::FactoryGirl`, I would start with greping tasks for 'FactoryGirl' string. You can also try executing task and when it fails add `--trace` at the end. Then you should have details in the output (file & line).

Answer (score 0):

I had this in `config/application.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:random_string) { |s| ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0, 30].join }
end
```

I changed it to this:

```
if Rails.env != "production"
  FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence(:random_string) { |s| ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0, 30].join }
  end 
end
```

The problem went away.